# C# using System.Drawing.Common; gives error name 'Common' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing'

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, system.drawing.common

I am having a C# WPF desktop app project on .NET6 in Visual Studio.

```
Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I've installed the package `System.Drawing.Common` from nuget for this project. The package seems to be in the project dependencies. There is a `<PackageReference>` to it. This strange error

```
CS0234
The type or namespace name 'Common' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

makes me crazy.

I don't understand if it's some weird conflict with the namespace of the package `System.Drawing` or something else. Visual Studio as always gives no clues, no solutions. ChatGPT has nothing to say about this except that I should add `<PackageReference>` to it. Forums don't seem to have anything about this issue.
Please could you help me understand. I am new to C#. It is so strange I struggle to simply add a pretty standard package to a very simple project.

Comment: There is nothing called `Common` in this package. Please show the code where you refer to the `Common` entity. Most likely this entity belongs to a different namespace.

Comment: As I understand it, `.Common` is an embedded namespace of the package `System.Drawing.Common` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/). The error above appears when I write `using System.Drawing.Common;`. If I omit this line, it starts to give an error for this code: `BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.StreamSource = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image));
bitmapImage.EndInit();
MyImage.Source = bitmapImage;` saying that "The name 'bitmapImage' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: `BitmapImage` is from `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`. What has GDI+ to do with this? -- If, for some reason, you need GDI+ (not that it appears you do), add `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` to the Project file

Comment: @Jimi, thank you for pointing out that BitmapImage is from System.Windows.Media.Imaging. I have `using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;` as well. So it is even more weird the compiler can't see the `BitmapImage` token. Apparently I added `Common` to use `Bitmap` in the following code: `Bitmap bitmap;
using(MemoryStream memoryStream=new MemoryStream()){
 BmpBitmapEncoder encoder=new BmpBitmapEncoder();
 encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
 encoder.Save(memoryStream);
 bitmap=new Bitmap(memoryStream);}
string filePath=iconPath;
bitmap.Save(filePath,ImageFormat.Icon);`

Comment: I realised that the latter error was a complaint not about the class `BitmapImage` but of the variable (its object) `bitmapImage`, which I created in another method. Totally removing the `using System.Drawing.Common;` helped to compile the project. Thank you.

Comment: As mentioned, if you need a System.Drawing.Bitmap, then add `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` to the Project's file (where you also have `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>`). After that, you can reference the `System.Drawing`  namespace -- If you need to generate ICON files in WPF, you may try [HL.IconPro](https://github.com/HerbertLausmann/HL.IconPro)